# bind9 restart fails - saying permission error

Tags: ubuntu, bind

am new here, i will be happy if i get some clue from you for my issue,

i have installed the bind9 in Ubuntu, it was successful in install and able to see the bind9 running,

then did a config based on my needs, now am not able to restart the bind.

please check the syslog am getting , it says some file permission issue,

```
Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: starting BIND 9.8.1-P1 -u bind

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--
infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' '--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' 'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2'

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: adjusted limit on open files from 4096 to 1048576

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: found 2 CPUs, using 2 worker threads

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: using up to 4096 sockets

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: loading configuration from '/etc/bind/named.conf'

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: reading built-in trusted keys from 
file '/etc/bind/bind.keys'

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: using default UDP/IPv4 port range: [1024, 65535]

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: using default UDP/IPv6 port range: [1024, 65535]

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: listening on IPv6 interfaces, port 53

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: listening on IPv4 interface lo, 127.0.0.1#53

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: binding TCP socket: address in use

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: listening on IPv4 interface eth1, 192.168.27.68#53

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: generating session key for dynamic DNS

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: sizing zone task pool based on 7 zones

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: using built-in root key for view _default

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: set up managed keys zone for view _default, 
file 'managed-keys.bind'

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: Warning: 'empty-zones-enable/disable-empty-zone' not 
set: disabling RFC 1918 empty zones

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: 254.169.IN-ADDR.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: 2.0.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: 100.51.198.IN-ADDR.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: 113.0.203.IN-ADDR.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: 255.255.255.255.IN-ADDR.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: 
0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: 
1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: D.F.IP6.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: 8.E.F.IP6.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: 9.E.F.IP6.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: A.E.F.IP6.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: B.E.F.IP6.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: automatic empty zone: 8.B.D.0.1.0.0.2.IP6.ARPA

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: command channel listening on 127.0.0.1#953



Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: command channel listening on ::1#953



Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: isc_stdio_open '/var/log/syslog' failed: permission denied

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: configuring logging: permission denied

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: loading configuration: permission denied

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: exiting (due to fatal error)

telxsi@telxsi-desktop:~$

telxsi@telxsi-desktop:~$
```

Note these error entries at the end:

```
Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: isc_stdio_open '/var/log/syslog' failed: permission denied

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: configuring logging: permission denied

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: loading configuration: permission denied

Jul 16 20:22:56 telxsi-desktop named[19659]: exiting (due to fatal error)
```

Answer (score 4):

You configured something similar to:

```
logging {
    channel default_file {
        file "/var/log/syslog" ...
    };
    category default { default_file; };
}
```

Whereas you should never write directly to /var/log/syslog. This file belongs to syslog and you can log to it only via syslog.

If you want your messages to end up in /var/log/syslog then convert to something along the lines of:

```
channel default_syslog {
    syslog daemon;        # send to syslog's daemon facility
    severity info;        # only send priority info and higher
};
category default { default_syslog; };
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that bind logs to syslog by default.